# Properly reference ddply in a package

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I created a package which heavily uses `dplyr`, in the meanwhile, this package needs to include a different function which relies on `ddply` from `plyr` package. Originally, I directly used `@import plyr`, but it caused naming conflicts which broke my other functions.

So I guess my only solution is to include necessary functions. Thus I added `@importFrom plyr ddply ldply llply`since `ldply llply` is used in `ddply`. However, it failed...

#### Some code sample

DESCRIPTION : I include `dplyr` and `plyr` under `Imports`

```
Package: My ProdComp
Type: Package
Imports:
    dplyr, plyr
```

NAMESPACE (generated by ROXYGEN2)

```
import(dplyr)
importFrom(plyr,ddply)
importFrom(plyr,ldply)
importFrom(plyr,llply)
```

Acturally script

```
#' @importFrom plyr ddply ldply llply
#' 
#' @import dplyr
#'
#' @export

final_table <- ddply(product_type_subset,.(general_category, product_type, cas), summarise, Value = toString(maximum_weight_fraction[!is.na(maximum_weight_fraction)]))
```

Error message

```
Error in as.quoted(.variables) : could not find function "."
```

So any suggestions on how to make it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is in `plyr`, not `dplyr`.

```
> dplyr::.
Error: '.' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'
> plyr::.
function (..., .env = parent.frame()) 
{
    structure(as.list(match.call()[-1]), env = .env, class = "quoted")
}
<environment: namespace:plyr>
```

So just import it from `plyr` along with the other functions.

Answer (score 2):

`plyr` is still nice for the `ldply`, `dlply`, `llply`, but if all you need is `ddply` just rewrite it using `dplyr`:

```
final_table <- ddply(product_type_subset,.(general_category, product_type, cas),
    summarise,
    Value = toString(maximum_weight_fraction[!is.na(maximum_weight_fraction)]))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
final_table <- group_by(product_type_subset, general_category, product_type, cas) %>%
    summarize_(Value = toString(maximum_weight_fraction[!is.na(maximum_weight_fraction)]))
```

It will be faster code and cut an unnecessary dependency (this is very nice from a maintenance point-of-view!).

Given that this is in a package, `R CMD CHECK` will give *"variable without visible binding"* warnings for either of the above. If you want to submit to CRAN, you'll need to use standard evaluating versions instead, like this:

```
final_table <- group_by_(product_type_subset, ~general_category, ~product_type, ~cas) %>%
    summarize_(Value = ~toString(maximum_weight_fraction[!is.na(maximum_weight_fraction)]))
```

I don't know offhand an easy way to make the `plyr` version standard-evaluating. You can use a character vector instead of `.()` for the `.variables` argument, but I don't know about the `Value =` bit.